# Vert.x fails to "Run your module and see your changes immediately"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, vert.x, redeploy

I am working with the Vert.x Gradle template hosted at the [Vert.x Github space](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-gradle-template).

The build file suggests that there is a runModIDEA target that runs IDEA-built class files so that rebuild/redeploy is not required to pick up changes:

```
runModIDEA - run the module from the project resources in IDEA. This allows you to run the module without building it
first!
```

... yet the task does not exist per ./gradlew tasks.

I am not tied to this particular build task per se.

*I just want a working auto-redeploy solution that enables me to see updates without a two minute rebuild/redeploy cycle.*

**EDIT**:  I also tried running it directly, pointing to InteliJ IDEA output classpath.  It works fine, but doesn't pick up changes.

```
vertx runmod com.mycompany~vert-x-reverse-proxy~1.0.0-final -c conf.json -cp out/production/vert-x-reverse-proxy
```

**EDIT**:  I also tried ./gradlew runmod -m, first changing vertx_classpath.txt so that the IDEA files (out/production) are looked at first.  Still no redeploy.  In fact, while it was running, I deleted the out directory and it continued working.

**EDIT**:  I also tried vertx run com.mycompany.myproject.ReverseProxyVerticle -c conf.json -cp out/production/vert-x-reverse-proxy... same results.  It ran as expected but did not pick up changes.  Only way to pick up changes was to gradlew clean and re-assemble.

**EDIT**:  I have been through [these instructions](http://vertx.io/dev_guide.html#run-your-module-and-see-your-changes-immediately) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, I had the same problem and managed to fix it by deleting everything under the /mods folder in the /target directory.  This is in fact mentioned in the vertx documentation - though maybe could be a little more emphatic. Once everything under /mods is removed, start up the application and it redeploys whenever anything is changed.

Comment: By the way - in order to see changes in client-side web resources I also needed to set the preserve-cwd flag to true in the mod.json - which forces the application to serve from the source folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to vertx and stumble with this problem or similar, it might be worth to have a look at this [vertx google group entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vertx/Failed$20in$20deploying$20module$20java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError$3A$20org$2Fvertx$2Fgroovy$2Fplatform$2FVerticle/vertx/dDbF5OG7sZQ/ZzFKJ_phPYgJ). It describes the changes that need to be done to the generated project by the Vertx Gradle Template to get it running. 
I know, this does not answer directly the question posted here but I hope it helps you further.